# Lichess Cloud Evaluation Flaw?

Tags: engines, evaluation, lichess

In the following position that's in the Traxler Counterattack: https://lichess.org/analysis/r1b1k2N/ppp1q1pp/5n2/3Pp3/2Bn4/8/PPPP1bPP/RNBQ1K1R_w_q_-_1_9

```
[fen "r1b1k2N/ppp1q1pp/5n2/3Pp3/2Bn4/8/PPPP1bPP/RNBQ1K1R w q - 1 9"]

9. d6 cxd6 10. Kxf2 Bg4 11. Qe1 (11. Qf1) Nxc2 12. Qf1 Nxa1 13. h3 Be6
```

The evaluation is "+0.4" at depth 54 if you enable cloud analysis on Lichess, suggesting a draw, with the following engine line: 9. d6 cxd6 10. Kxf2 Bg4 11. Qe1 Nxc2 12. Qf1 Nxa1 13. h3 Be6. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0hGe.jpg)

What happens if the game continues: 9. d6 cxd6 10. Kxf2 Bg4 11. Qf1 instead? Lichess Stockfish evaluates this at +3 at lower depths but according to the previous analysis, at depth 54 it showed +0.4. What is the drawing line after 9. ...cxd6 (I know 9. ...Qxd6 draws but according to the cloud evaluation so did 9. ...cxd6)? Or is this an incorrect evaluation at depth 54?

Answer (score 2):

You are right this is a flaw. Although the best move `d6` is correct, the subsequent move is not — cxd6 is wrong, correct is Qxd6.

Analysis of latest stockfish (130222, stronger than current released version 14.1) on my desktop at multipv=2 reaching depths 58 and 57.

r1b1k2N/ppp1q1pp/5n2/3Pp3/2Bn4/8/PPPP1bPP/RNBQ1K1R w q - 1 9

```
0.00/58 9.d6 Qxd6 10.Nf7 Qe7 11.c3 Bg4 12.Qa4+ Nd7 13.Kxf2 Qh4+ 14.Kf1 Bh5 15.cxd4 Qf4+ 16.Kg1 Qxd4+ 17.Kf1 Qf4+ 18.Ke1 Qe4+ 19.Kf2 Qf4+
```

```
0.00/57 9.h3 Bh4 10.c3 Nf5 11.d4 Bd7 12.Kg1 O-O-O 13.Nd2 exd4 14.Nf3 Bg3 15.Nxd4 Ne4 16.Nf7 Nxd4 17.cxd4 Bf2+ 18.Kh2 Rf8 19.Ne5 Bg3+ 20.Kg1 Qh4 21.Qd3 Bf2+ 22.Kh2 b5 23.Bb3 Bg3+ 24.Kg1 Bf2+
```